# docker-compose.yml logging driver needs to configurable

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml in which I have mention logging driver as fluentd.
But I want logging driver to be enabled or disabled with a flag.(That means whenever I need, I can enable the logging driver or can disable completly)

Also I want to make IP address and port configurable. How can I change them whenever I need?

```
srvc-name:
 image: <DOCKER-REISTRY-PATH:IMAGE-NAME>
 environment:
  - "JAVA_OPTS=-XX:MaxRAM=4g"
 logging:
  driver: "fluentd"
  options:
    fluentd-address: localhost:24224
    fluentd-async-connect: "true"
    tag: tag.name
 volumes:
  - app-name-config:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/app1
  - app-name-logs:/usr/local/tomcat/logs
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Since I am  new to docker, so not sure what are the options to get solution for above scenario. Let me know if you have any idea?

Comment: Could you use an [override file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) to provide the logging configuration and other deployment-specific settings?